# Create button that toggles visibility of table rows that do not contain specific text color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, datatables

I'm using the [DataTables jQuery plugin](http://datatables.net/) to format a `<table>`, and I want to create a button that toggles visibility of any `<tr>` that does not contain `<span>` w/ text color #bfbfff. The table is structured like this:

```
<a id="notes">Filter</a>

<table id="qpidvulh_to-do_list">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span style="color: #bfbfff">Content</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Content</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The jQuery I've come up with that doesn't work thus far:

```
$("a#notes").on("click", function() {
    if ($('#qpidvulh_to-do_list tr span:not').css('color') == '#bfbfff') {
        $(this).parent("tr").toggle();
    }
} );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/wuekkt88/4/)

Comment: `.css('color')` returns **RGB** format color. The `'#bfbfff'` HEX is `rgb(191, 191, 255)` http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/yq1uhc23/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems:

---

### 1. You are not importing jQuery.

Fix that.

---

### 2. span:not is not the right selector

Simply select all of the spans that have the right style attribute. Then hide the parent `<tr>` of that span.

```
$("#qpidvulh_to-do_list tr td span[style='color:#b3b3ff;']").closest("tr").toggle();
```

---

### Edit:

Here is the code for the non-colored spans being hidden.

```
$("#qpidvulh_to-do_list tr").toggle();
$("#qpidvulh_to-do_list tr td span[style='color:#b3b3ff;']").closest("tr").toggle();
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuekkt88/5/)

Comment: He wants to toggle the ones that does not have the colored span.

Comment: Do you have a version of this that toggles the spans without the color?

Answer (score 2):

May be a little bit overdone but works (althought I can't find myself shorter solution in this particular case). The thing is that `css('color')` returns color in RGB format.

```
$("a#notes").on("click", function() {
    $('#qpidvulh_to-do_list tr span').each(function(){
        if ($(this).css('color') != 'rgb(191, 191, 255)') {
            $(this).closest("tr").toggle();
        }
    })
});
```

**EDIT**

You can use this even if the *style* attribute contains multiple properties and whitespaces, like: `<span style="color : #bfbfff; font-size:20px;">`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/yq1uhc23/10/)(updated)